# How can I select and save data row in a table? C# ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have to select rows from a table and then I have to send it to my data base in SQL SERVER to process that data. I thought that I can save this selected items into a JSON string and then the Stored Procedure can receive that string.

I have this in my .cshtml file:

```
@model List<model.entity.Recibo>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Recibos Pendientes";
}

<h2>RecibosPendientes</h2>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table">
        <tr class="btn-success">
            <th></th>
            <th>ID Recibo</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Concepto de Cobro</th>
            <th>Seleccionar</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var objetoRecibo in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="~/Recibo/ReciboPendiente/@objetoRecibo.IdRecibo">Ver</a></td>
            <td>@objetoRecibo.IdRecibo</td>
            <td>@objetoRecibo.FechaEm</td>
            <td>@objetoRecibo.NombreCC</td>

            <td><input name="RecibosMarcados" type="checkbox" value="False" /> </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="fa-cc-visa" onclick="">Pagar</button>
</div>
```

It looks like this.
[image: Table that I have to select a row]

I am not pretty sure how to save the selected ID columns and save it into a JSON string when I press the **Pagar** button.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `<Form>` tag, and the id that you want to send should be put in a hidden input. e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="IdRecibo[@objetoRecibo.IdRecibo]" value="@objetoRecibo.IdRecibo">
```

The name is made unique by having an array notation in the name attribute.  You need to have a method to deal with the form post request as well.  I suggest having a read about that in an asp.net book or [microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/).